# ERROR Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 () en angular

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot

ERRORES:

```html
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
login:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
core.js:7187 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":"http://localhost:8080/login","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/login: 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at zone-evergreen.js:707
    at SafeSubscriber._error (Observable.js:91)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:135)
    at Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at FilterSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:7187
```

Servicio POST en java spring boot del servidor (url del microservicio: http: localhost: 8080 / login):

```html
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
public class dmoController {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody String data) {
 System.out.print("entra");
 System.out.print(data);
 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
 headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
 headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
 headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,content-type");
 headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
 return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    
}
```

Llamada al post desde el angular (url angular: http: localhost: 4200 / login):

```html
 public async login(email: string, password: string) {
        const data = { username: 'pepa', password: 'manoli' };

        httpOptions.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        httpOptions.headers.append(
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
            'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE',
        );
        httpOptions.headers.append(
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
            'X-Requested-With,content-type',
        );
        httpOptions.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

        this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(data), httpOptions).toPromise();
    }
```

Necesito que me ayudeis a solucionar estos errores, lo he probado todo, poner un proxy en angular etc...

No se que más hacer alguien que le haya pasado lo mismo me puede hechar una mano?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta arrancar el navegador desactivando los ajustes de seguridad. De este modo no se comprobaran las CORS y no debería darte error.

Si usas Mac puedes arrancar Chrome con los ajustes deshabilitados con la siguiente instrucción en la terminal:

```
"/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir
```

Una vez abierto verás que aparece un mensaje arriba indicando que estas en modo "no seguro".

Abre http://localhost:4200 para visualizar tu aplicación y el error de CORS no debería aparecer.

Saludos!